# spring.data.rest.basePath is not applied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I want to apply prefix to rest api path `/api`:

I added in application.properties these lines:

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
server.servlet.context-path=/api
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

But after I deploy the code in Wildfly it's not working:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.6</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>8.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>datalis_admin</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>10</source>
                        <target>10</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Application start method:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "org.admin.*", "org.plugin.service" })
@EntityScan("org.plugin.entity")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For some reason `/api` is not added into mapped end points:

```
2018-10-08 12:32:19,060 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.get(java.lang.String)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,061 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/{id}],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.save(java.lang.String,org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,064 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.create(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,065 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.data.domain.Page<org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsDTO> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.find(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PaymentTransactionsFilterDTO,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,069 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/export],methods=[GET]}" onto public void org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.export(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,073 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/transactions/types],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.PaymentTransactionsController.getTypes()
2018-10-08 12:32:19,078 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/users/reset],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.UserController.reset(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PasswordResetDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,079 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/users/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.UserController.token(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PasswordResetDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,080 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/users/request],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.UserController.resetRequest(org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.PasswordResetDTO)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,092 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-08 12:32:19,093 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: which spring-boot version are you?

Comment: did you tried to access any path like /api/users/token as mapped logs will show with your controller path but check before app start "Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/api'"

Comment: it should show your context path in last..

Comment: I use Wildfly for app server.

Comment: did you tried to access your path with conext path..means try to access you api with /api prefix as server.servlet.context-path=/api sufficient to set context path..and see complete logs somewhere it should be showing your context path..

Comment: sorry missed the communication..it will not work as it will work only for embedded servers so you need to configure jboss xml..for it

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @Peter Penzov, Try to use the same configuration with `embedded tomcat` and it must works fine without any additional configuration

Comment: How about Wildfly Servlet-Only Distribution? Is this embedded version?

Answer (score 2):

All of the `server.*` properties that Spring Boot supports only apply to the configuration of the embedded servlet container  `(Tomcat, Jetty, or Undertow)`.

If you're deploying your Spring Boot app to a standalone server/Jboss Wildfly then you'll need to configure that server using whatever mechanisms it provides.

Please configure context-root variable by settings in jboss-web.xml file .

this is how you can do this in the by adding a /WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file in the application that you deploy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/api</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

**UPDATE**

if an application has the name package_admin and did not have the context root configured, the application should be called using the entire file name; so in your case if you would like to have api as default context path in wildfly then use api as your war file name if you haven't not configured context path explicitly..

however, we want the application be called only with a much simpler context root (for example, /api/) but file names always want manage versioning etc so its always good idea to configure the context root of the application.

> To perform this configuration it is necessary to create a new file
>   within the application's WEB-INF folder; this is the same directory
>   where the web.xml file is located.
>
> This setting is made for a file called jboss-web.xml that should be
>   placed in the WEB-INF...

Comment: I was hoping to create Spring war package for Tomcat and Wildfly. Is there some other way to apply server.servlet.context-path= on Wildfly?

Comment: for tomcat deploy, you can define in server.xml like <Context path="/api"/>

Comment: How I can find why server.servlet.context-path=/api is not applied. Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Server.servlet.context-path will work only with embedded server, if you are using embedded server then look at logs before sever start and show me what logs are showing for context path a blank or /api. You can trace the logs, let me see that package so you can put in debug for that package in sprint boot but let me know if it’s not working in embedded server ?

Comment: org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver=debug add this property in application property to debug properties...

Comment: Here is the output after I added the debug property: https://pastebin.com/XE92wAn5

Comment: So your connect path show package_admin on line 92 and 93, you can deploy to default as api should change default path to api

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by `you can deploy to default as api should change default path to api`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181656/discussion-between-kj007-and-peter-penzov).

Answer (score 1):

I've reached this result using an `AbstractController`

```
@RequestMapping("api")
public abstract class AbstractController {}
```

Other controllers will extend this one

I've not test but it should be possible also using the following property `server.servlet.context-path`

But i think this works only if you run your project with `mvn spring-boot:run` because the servlet-engine or application server has a descriptor to assign a path of a deployed war application.

Comment: I tried your proposal but the result is the same - it's not applied. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you give some idea how I can debug the application why `spring.data.rest.base-path` is not applied?

Comment: Yeah... you can inject  with `@Autowire org.springframework.core.env.Environment env` and use `env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path")` for a specific property